# Failed to copy files to Macintosh_HD

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to copy files from the server to Macintosh_HD (`/Volumes/Macintosh_HD`) via scp: `scp -r username@IP:directory-path .`

But it is showing an error:

> Permission denied, please try again.

I am logged in as admin, and the above command is working fine while copying in `/Users/home`.

Kindly suggest the probable solution.

Comment: Do you have read permission on `directory-path`? Do you have write permission on `.` (to verify, run `touch a-test-file; rm a-test-file`)? If you are copying directories, do you have write permissions to all already-existing directories with the same name beneath `.`?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.I have read permission on directory path, and write permission in dirctory of server. But I am not able to create any directory in Mac_HD via terminal (mkdir command in /Volumes/Macintosh_HD

Comment: Can you test if `touch /foo` as admin works?

Answer (score 1):

The `Permission denied, please try again.` is because your password for `username` was not correct.

If it were a file permissions issue, the error would tell you the path it was having trouble with.

```
$ scp user@host:/var/root/ /tmp/
scp: /var/root: Permission denied

$ scp user@host:Desktop/*.xls /var/root/
/var/root//test.xls: Permission denied
```